# Pass read only property to another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

In Objective C, I have the Core Data managedObjectContext implemented like so:

```
//MyViewController1.h

@interface MyViewController1 : UIViewController 
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *_managedObjectContext;
}
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

//MyViewController.m

@implementation MyViewController1

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;

- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{
...
}
```

(Yes, I know my code is terribly dated, it's an old project).

I want to pass this `managedObjectContext` as a parameter to another `UIViewController` so it can hold on to the `managedObjectContext`. How would I declare the property? Currently, in `MyViewController2`, I have it declared the same way as in `MyViewController1`:

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

But when I do `self.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContextParameter` in the constructor of `MyViewController2.m`, the compiler won't let me assign because it's read only.

What is the best way to do this? Should I just do it without the readonly or have some kind of weak reference? I get lost with these kinds of things.

Comment: Removing `readonly` seems like the obvious choice. Why did you add it if you need the property to be writable?

Comment: @rmaddy I believe that was from the boiler plate code from Apple a long time ago. Could I make the property readonly in ViewController1, and the property it's passed to in ViewController2 able to be read? That works with the compiler, but not sure if it makes sense design wise. But yeah may end up just not making them read only like you say.